# Where can I see what caused Windows to make the 'hardware disconnected' sound?

Tags: windows-8, usb, power-supply, event-viewer

Whenever I switch my desk fan on or off, Windows makes a sound as if a USB device is being (dis)connected. I haven't been able to determine which device is being affected by the power spike, so I hoped Windows could tell me. I've tried using Event Viewer, but the 'Hardware Events' log is empty. Perhaps it's possible to enable logging of less 'severe' hardware events somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

You could use this usb logging program - http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_log_view.html

It tells you what gets plugged in when.

Answer (score 0):

Try to unplug all your USB devices, repeating the steps you took to create the sound. Now one by one plug them back in and keep checking if that device caused the problem.

Another way might be to take a look at the 'safely remove hardware' menu via the tray icon before and after the sound.

Comment: Disconnected all devices, I had. Still made that sound, the laptop did. In the garbage, the laptop was put. Survived, the laptop has not.